# Developing console applications for previous assemblies (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, taxonomy, console-application

I Made a console application that changes items in a list that has a Taxonomy field.
The app works well on the Developement machine, but for some reason, when move it to production, we get this error:

> "Unable to Install or run the application. the application requiers
>   that assembly Microsoft.IdentityManagement.ExternalSettingsManager
>   Version 4.0.2450.47 be installed in the global assembly cache first

I did some testing and it seems this error doesnt occur if the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxonomy` isn't referenced in the project. Also, if i set the requested assembly as "Included" in the project properties, It just asks for a different Assembly.

*This might be important: the developement machine i worked on has updated for sharepoint installed that are not installed yet on the production env.

Answer (score 0):

Your last point is very important as it sounds like your solution is binding to a newer version of the DLL than is available in Production.  Your Development environment should *always* be the same version and patch level as your production environment or even a little bit older, if absolutely necessary.

One thing that might work is to edit your solution, right-click on the DLL reference in question and make sure that the 'Specific Version' property is set to false.  This sometimes can make the difference.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately I already tried that, but to no effect.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest would be to copy the DLLs from production to a local folder on your dev machine (not the GAC) and bind to those instead of the ones in the GAC.

Comment: Apparently that doesn't work as well. We eventually solved this by just compiling the code from another machine that had the same assembly files. But I can't help but wonder what the problem was..

Comment: There must be something else going on then because I use this approach regularly to build SP2010 targeted console apps on my SP2007 farm.

Comment: The problem seems to originate from the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxonomy assembly only (as far as i can tell). other sharepoint dlls work fine
I'm still looking for what is causing this, I'll post updates if I find anything for future reference.